# FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist in Spring boot backend

Tags: java, spring-boot, firebase, spring-security, jwt

I have been working on my open-source project and in its backend, I am implementing JWT authentication and alongside that I am using Firebase for database.

But I am getting these errors suddenly after implementing JWT authentication:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:602) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:489) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:183) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtAuthenticationFilter' defined in file [C:\Users\anant.s.raghuvanshi\Documents\Projects\CodeCraft\hub-backend\target\classes\com\CodeCraft\hubbackend\configuration\JwtAuthenticationFilter.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'applicationConfig' defined in file [C:\Users\anant.s.raghuvanshi\Documents\Projects\CodeCraft\hub-backend\target\classes\com\CodeCraft\hubbackend\configuration\ApplicationConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [C:\Users\anant.s.raghuvanshi\Documents\Projects\CodeCraft\hub-backend\target\classes\com\CodeCraft\hubbackend\service\UserService.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.CodeCraft.hubbackend.service.UserService]: Constructor threw exception
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1189) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:210) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:173) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:168) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:153) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:86) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:261) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:235) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:52) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4886) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1328) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1318) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:846) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1328) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1318) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:241) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:918) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:485) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationConfig' defined in file [C:\Users\anant.s.raghuvanshi\Documents\Projects\CodeCraft\hub-backend\target\classes\com\CodeCraft\hubbackend\configuration\ApplicationConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [C:\Users\anant.s.raghuvanshi\Documents\Projects\CodeCraft\hub-backend\target\classes\com\CodeCraft\hubbackend\service\UserService.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.CodeCraft.hubbackend.service.UserService]: Constructor threw exception
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1189) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:888) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [C:\Users\anant.s.raghuvanshi\Documents\Projects\CodeCraft\hub-backend\target\classes\com\CodeCraft\hubbackend\service\UserService.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.CodeCraft.hubbackend.service.UserService]: Constructor threw exception
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1314) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:888) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    ... 77 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.CodeCraft.hubbackend.service.UserService]: Constructor threw exception
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:224) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    ... 89 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. 
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.java:161) ~[firebase-admin-9.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.java:132) ~[firebase-admin-9.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient.getFirestore(FirestoreClient.java:68) ~[firebase-admin-9.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.CodeCraft.hubbackend.service.UserService.<init>(UserService.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:198) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    ... 91 common frames omitted
```

Before implementing that, the backend was perfectly getting started and the basic functionalities were working fine.

Here is the Github repo link:- *https://github.com/anantraghuvanshi/CodeCraft-Hub*

Also, here is the User and UserService classes:-
**User.java**

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User implements UserDetails {

    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**UserService.java:**

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    private final Firestore dbFirestore = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();

    public Optional<User> findByUsername(String username) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        DocumentReference docRef = dbFirestore.collection("users").document(username);
        ApiFuture<DocumentSnapshot> future = docRef.get();
        DocumentSnapshot document = future.get();

        if (document.exists()) {
            return Optional.ofNullable(document.toObject(User.class));
        } else {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
    public boolean existsByUsername(String username) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        DocumentReference docRef = dbFirestore.collection("users").document(username);
        ApiFuture<DocumentSnapshot> future = docRef.get();
        return future.get().exists();
    }
    public boolean existsByEmail(String email) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        CollectionReference users = dbFirestore.collection("users");
        Query query = users.whereEqualTo("email", email);
        ApiFuture<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshot = query.get();

        return !querySnapshot.get().getDocuments().isEmpty();
    }
    public User findByUsernameRepo(String username) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        DocumentReference docRef = dbFirestore.collection("users").document(username);
        ApiFuture<DocumentSnapshot> future = docRef.get();
        DocumentSnapshot document = future.get();

        if (document.exists()) {
            return document.toObject(User.class);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public void save(User user){
        CollectionReference userRef = dbFirestore.collection("users");
        userRef.add(user);
    }
}
```

Now here are the files where I have implemented JWT authentication:
**ApplicationConfig.java:**

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Autowired
    private final UserService userService;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
        return username -> {
            try {
                return userService.findByUsernameRepo(username);
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passWordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passWordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

**JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:**

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
                                    @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
                                    @NonNull FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        final String userEmail;
        if(authHeader == null || authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")){
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
        userEmail = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);
        if(userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null){
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
            if(jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)){
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                authToken.setDetails(
                        new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource()
                                .buildDetails(request)
                );
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

**JwtService.java:**

```
@Service
public class JwtService {

    private static final String SECRET_KEY = "some_string";
    public String extractUsername(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver){
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails){
        return generateToken(new HashMap<>(), userDetails);
    }

    public String generateToken(
            Map<String, Object> extraClaims,
            UserDetails userDetails
    ){
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(extraClaims)
                .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+ 1000 * 60 * 24))
                .signWith(getSignInKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                .compact();
    }

    public boolean isTokenValid(String token, UserDetails userDetails){
        final String userName =  extractUsername(token);
        return (userName.equals(userDetails.getUsername())) && !isTokenExpired(token);
    }

    private boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    private Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token){
        return Jwts.parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(getSignInKey())
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
    }

    private Key getSignInKey() {
        byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(SECRET_KEY);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfig.java:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests().
                requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        ;
        return http.build();
    }


}
```

Now here is the **FirebaseConfig.java** where I am initializing firebase:

```
@Configuration
public class FirebaseConfig {

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() throws IOException {
        FileInputStream serviceAccount =
                new FileInputStream("./serviceAccountKey.json");

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .build();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

    }
}
```

**pom.xml**:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-admin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-impl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId> <!-- or jjwt-gson if Gson is preferred -->
            <version>0.11.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Here's all what I have implemented, and I have tried doing certain things like I have checked whether Firebase is getting properly initialized or not but that didnt help.
I am expecting that the backend should get started properly and other functionalities should work fine.